# How to use: sonata_type_model_list

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, sonata-admin

I'm trying to run this code:

```
if(!$this->isChild()) {
        $formMapper->add('post', 'sonata_type_model', array(), array('edit' => 'list'));
```

From this tutorial: http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/2-1/doc/tutorial/creating_your_first_admin_class/defining_admin_class.html

I'm aware that you have to use sonata_type_model_list as of 2.1

> sonata_type_model_list : this type replaces the option edit = list provided as a 4th argument on the sonata_type_model

The problem is that I have absolutely no idea how to do that.  I have found ZERO examples anywhere after a whole day of google searches. All I want to do is replace the edit=>list with sonata_type_model_list.

Can you please tell me how to do that in the code above?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I used it in my code. However it's not working in all browsers. When I select the taget entity the form value in the parent view doesn't get updated (FireFox and IE).

```
$formMapper->
...
->add('image', 'sonata_type_model_list', 
       array(
           'compound' => true,
           'by_reference' => true
            )
      )
...
```

I also find it very hard to find some tutorials/examples on how to use this type. Best thing you can do is to go through their source code. Which is awful time consuming.

One way I found out how to configure these form types is to provide a wrong argument.

```
e.g. 'my_compound' => true,
```

This will result in an error telling you that 'my_compound' isn't a valid parameter and also will show you a list of valid parameters.
Hope this helps!

Comment: I guess that at least gives an example. Unfortunately I can't really test it with the code above because I just gave up and switched to rails... I really thank you for replying though... TWELVE DAYS! I usually get answers to Rails questions in about 3 minutes. :) I've been wrestling with Symfony for years now... but I finally got tired of spending more time programming Symfony than programming the site.